# Error on creating a new website bucket with PutBucketWebSite

Tags: amazon-s3

When trying to create a new WebSiteBucket on S3, I get this (understood) error.
Off course I don't have the bucket. I'm trying to create a new one.

Error: "The specified bucket does not exist"

Code:

```
        using (AmazonS3 client = AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client(
            System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AWSAccessKey"],
            System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AWSSecretKey"],
            S3Config))
        {

            WebsiteConfiguration wSite = new WebsiteConfiguration();
            wSite.IndexDocumentSuffix = "Index.HTML";
            wSite.ErrorDocument = "Error.HTML";

            PutBucketWebsiteRequest request = new PutBucketWebsiteRequest();
            request.BucketName = bucket_name;
            request.WebsiteConfiguration = wSite;

            PutBucketWebsiteResponse response = client.PutBucketWebsite(request);

        }
```

Help please.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This all code written above is to [set website configuration](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2011/02/host-your-static-website-on-amazon-s3.html) on S3 bucket that must exist in your S3 account. That's why its throwing error about "The specified bucket does not exist" on setting website configuration.

To set website configuration you require to set Index.html as your index page and Error.html as error page. These two files (Index.html and Error.html) should exist in your S3 Bucket to set website configuration.

To create bucket you can use this REST API to [Create Bucket](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketPUT.html).

Thanks